# JQuery .height(x) is doubled in IE8?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a series of Divs in a wrapper, and I need to equalize the height of the two columns. We are using a simple jQuery plugin to do this, which fires the following function:

```
//find heights of all children, and find the tallest
this.each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > tallest) {
        tallest = $(this).height();
    }
});
if ((maxHeight) && tallest > maxHeight) tallest = maxHeight;
//assign the tallest height to all child elements
return this.each(function() {
    console.log('tallest: ' + tallest);
    $(this).height(tallest).css("overflow", "visible");
});
```

`console.log` is showing a height of 2131px in IE8, however, the target div is being given a height of 4262 px (exactly double?). I stepped through the code, and I see that `.height(tallest)` is being executed with the proper value, but somehow IE8 **and only IE8** is giving it double height.

**Edit:**

So far I have tried `.height(2131)` `.height('2131px')` `.css("height","2131px")`, and `.css('min-height', "2131px")`. All with the same effect. Coming up with a use case might be a bit difficult as this is a big, "enterprisey" system, but I'll see if I can replicate it...

Comment: Does this also happen if you only just execute `$(some_element).height(2131)`? Perhaps providing a test case is helpful since I cannot reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/9C6Qe/

Comment: Try outerHeight(), see if that makes a difference.

Comment: What happens if you take out large parts of or even all of the stylesheets? I've seen IE8 & jQuery behave very strange (up to crashing the JS engine and not showing a page at all) with particularly complex CSS files (i.e. the problem turned out to be the css, not the JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though whoever coded the page before I was responsible for maintaining it had an extra closing  tag, messing the whole thing up. 9_9

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing is, the [.height() jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/) shows a lot of IE8 remarks in the comments, ultimately leading to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686836/how-to-make-this-jquery-snippet-work-in-internet-explorer) which may help you as well.

Comment: unfortunately I am in IE8 compatability mode, using the html 5 doctype, and confirmed using this script: `javascript:window.alert('You are in ' + (document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'?'Standards':'Quirks') + ' mode.')`

Comment: Ah shame. In that case I second @pimvdb's comment to your question: a test case would be nice to help out any further.